# Как взломать (предсказать) генератор случайных чисел?

Tags: математика, случайные-числа, криптография

Если нейросеть, которой будет скормлена достаточно большая выборка чисел, полученных из генератора (он, допустим, их генерит на основании шумов радио) будет выдавать на выходе те числа, которые сделал сам генератор, но которые не вошли в выборку для обучения. Будет ли этот генератор считаться взломанным?

Comment: по идее будет взломан только принцип генерации

Comment: *будет выдавать на выходе те числа ,которые сделал сам генератор* Она может выдать те числа, которые УЖЕ были сгенерированы, и скормлены нейросети на стадии обучения. А вот предсказания последовательности, генерируемой ПОСЛЕ обучения - не ждите. На то он и шум...

Comment: @Akina А есть ли какой-то способ сравнить криптостойкость генераторов?(просто нужно для учебы) Изначально предполагал скармливать псевдослучайные и случайные числа одному алгоритму шифрования и ломать его,сравнивая время ,затраченное на это. Но с этим видимо не получится

Comment: очень не люблю такие ответы, но в данном случае просто не могу не послать на Википедию: [Тестирование псевдослучайных последовательностей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Comment: почитайте здесь:
https://habr.com/post/151187/

Comment: @Akina а если тестировать случайную последовательность ?(да,заваливаю вас дурацкими вопросами,но только потому ,что пока крайне неопытен в данном вопросе) Достаточно будет провести ряд статистических тестов ,описанных в той же Википедии?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets спасибо,но уже читал и даже на будущее оставил вкладку ,т.к. может понадобиться